# How to have an input be equal to a variable

Tags: python

So, I'm not really sure how to explain this so I'll give an example.

ex.
If I input: "Iowa"
I want to be able to look up the number 3

This is what I have so far, but it returns 0

```
school=input('Select your school: ')

Illinois=['Illinois',2]
Indiana=['Indiana',2]
Iowa=['Iowa',3]

print(school[1])
```

Comment: use dictionary  for this

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Answer (score 0):

```
lookup = {'Illinois':2,'Indiana':2,'Iowa':3}
print(lookup.get('Iowa'))
```

use `dictionary` for this

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14496614)

Comment: @Mack, Can you let me know why this will not return 3. or why this does not solve this "If I input: "Iowa" I want to be able to look up the number 3"

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to Save all your variables in a **lookup dictionary** so that we can find it with its **key-value**

```
lookup = {'Illinois':2,'Indiana':2,'Iowa':3}
```

then if necessary you can ask user to input proper key/name of the school

```
while True:
    try:
        school=raw_input('Select your school: ')
        if school in lookup:
            print(lookup.get(school))
            break
        else:
             school=raw_input('Select proper your school: ')
    except ValueError:
        print "Error: Invalid school."
```